# Using VPN Plugin in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I'm trying to use the following plugin in my ionic project

> https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-vpn

I have installed already the plugin with:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vpn
```

I have no idea how I have to define the import

```
import { VPNManager } from '.....';
```

for using this plugin.

Answer (score 3):

vpn plugin is not part of the ionic-native package. So, You wont be able to import it using the ES6 way. But by default, All the cordova plugins are accessible through the Webview's "window" object. So, In this case, you can access it using window.cordova.plugin [ replace plugin with the exported plugin accessor ]. If you are not sure about the name of the accessor, console.log(window.cordova) to see the plugins you have access to.

NOTE : If you are not able to directly access the cordova plugins using the .(dot) notation, you can access it using : window["cordova"]["plugin"].

Comment: hi i am facing same issue  please help me my issue is , (node:32320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
(rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Variable(s) missing (use: --variable
ALLOWWIFI=value).

Answer (score 1):

There is no ionic-native wrapper class available for this plugin, so no need to import anything. To use it tell typescript the the plugin handle exists:

```
declare var VPNManager;
```

And then use it like that:

```
VPNManager.enable(...);
```

No need to directly access the `window` object, cordova/ionic takes care of that.